# css linear-gradient in Internet Explorer 9 or in old a version

Tags: html, css

I use linear gradient tag for making skewed line 1px width. In IE this like looks blurred. Other browsers (Opera, Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari) show this line correctly.

```
@media (min-width: 986px) {
     .issue .issue-descr {
         border-top: solid 1px #fff;
     }
     .issue .issue-descr:after {
        content: "";
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% - 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% + 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);      
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% - 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% + 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);      
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% - 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% + 1px),  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%); 
        background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% - 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% + 1px), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        width: 40px;
        height: 30px;
    } 
}
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rru7lqu1obshalo/internetExplorer.jpg?dl=0 IE
https://www.dropbox.com/s/33mi3zhd3oys12t/chrome.jpg?dl=0 - Google Chrome

Comment: please format your code

Comment: I'd recommend using [ColorZIlla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). Easy to use and supports I.E 6-9. Just make the gradient you want and copy and paste it in your code.

Comment: Yeah, ColorZilla is solution for you!

Comment: This might be a bug, check http://jsfiddle.net/grLz3csg/1/, first run is buggy, but if you click on "Run" again then it'll be rendered fine, It also occurs on ie11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed

> @media (min-width: 986px) {
>        .issue .issue-descr {
>            border-top: solid 1px #fff;
>        }
>        .issue .issue-descr:after {
>           content: "";         background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% - 1px),
>   rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 25px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) calc(50% + 1px),
>   rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20px);    width:40px;  height: 30px;
>       }  }